# Does fate act in such a detailed and planned manner

Tags: karma, destiny

Something really unbelievable / unexpected happened to me recently - I was about to get a new job and move to a new company. Within no time I lost both my current job and my new job.

When I think back I realise that the sequence of events leading up to my acceptance of the new job etc. seem to be planned in extreme detail with the end objective in mind - loss of both jobs.

Is this possible or am I reading too much into it?

Comment: That's why Niyati or fate is often called a dancer. No one knows what move will She perform next :/

Comment: I think you are reading too much in it.